# Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable

Tags: python, environment-variables, apple-m1

i'm using m1 macbook

on zsh terminal,
I command
python3 --version
then it shows version
but python --version

```
zsh: command not found: python
```

what maybe the problem?

I tried pyenv then install ,
but it cause different error

```
pedrojung@pedroui-MacBookPro newtemp % pyenv install 2.7.5                          
Downloading openssl-1.0.2k.tar.gz...
-> https://pyenv.github.io/pythons/6b3977c61f2aedf0f96367dcfb5c6e578cf37e7b8d913b4ecb6643c3cb88d8c0
Installing openssl-1.0.2k...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.3 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/j_/1jx3n6k9085b2zsqpw92n84c0000gn/T/python-build.20220322161549.77349
Results logged to /var/folders/j_/1jx3n6k9085b2zsqpw92n84c0000gn/T/python-build.20220322161549.77349.log

Last 10 log lines:
      _dgram_write in libcrypto.a(bss_dgram.o)
      _RAND_query_egd_bytes in libcrypto.a(rand_egd.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [link_a.darwin] Error 1
make[3]: *** [do_darwin-shared] Error 2
make[2]: *** [libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [shared] Error 2
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

Comment: macOS Monterey 12.3 removed pre-bundled python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the absence of the `python` command:

- `python` - calls Python 2
- `python3` - calls Python 3

If you want to call Python 3 with the `python` command you can create a symbolic link. **Warning: only run this command if you really need to!**

Command: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

---

About the `pyenv` error: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386` - this means that the installer is alive with the **Intel x86** architecture and you have the **Apple M1** architecture.

Comment: Doesn't work in MacOS Monterey `ln: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted`